# In File maker Pro ,issue with tab control within tab control

Tags: tabcontrol, filemaker

I have two tab controls,each tab control has two tabs in it.My first tab in the first tab control has two buttons. When I click the first button,my first tab in the second tab control should be shown and my first tab control should be hidden(which is done by 'GO to Object' navigation command). And same way if I click second button,second tab of the second tab control should be displayed and my first tab control should be hidden(which is also done by 'GO to Object' navigation command).But now when I click any of the buttons,my first tab control does not hide.
Please someone suggest me some solution on this.

Comment: Welcome to SO :-)
Did you [create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If so, show us please

Comment: Do you actually mean you're *hiding* the first tab control or you're navigating to it's second tab?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I understand your question, I suspect you may not have named your tab segments correctly. The Go to Object command relies on the object's name, which is defined in the Name property in the Inspector (not the tab segments title, defined in the Tab Control setup).

Comment: Thanks for your reply.As told by you I checked for the tab segments names.I did correctly mention them in the inspector.Is it possible for this problem,because of moving any one of the tab control setup? Please clarify my doubt. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is difficult to understand the issue, so you should post screenshots.